# Octave plotting x axis precision

Tags: matlab, octave

I wonder how can I increase the precision of the x/y axis when I am plotting the graph.

I have initialised the `option long`
and I have a data set for example:

```
x(1:3) 
ans = 

736330.576631944 
736330.576643519 
736330.576655093 

y(1:3) 
ans = 

-62 
-63 
-62
```

and when I do plot(x(1:3),y(1,3)), i can only see a straight vertical line between -62 and -63, it seems like that the x axis doesnt have enough decimal places to recognise the changes.

```
get(gca, 'xticklabel') 
ans = 
{ 
[1,1] = -2e+006 
[1,2] = -1.5e+006 
[1,3] = -1e+006 
[1,4] = -500000 
[1,5] = 0 
[1,6] = 500000 
[1,7] = 1e+006 
[1,8] = 1.5e+006 
}
```

This is what I get from the get gca() function. Is there anyway to increase the precision of the x axis so that I can see the data point moving ?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Try setting your `xlim` manually to be around your necessary scale. Otherwise, consider shifting your whole `x` data set by 736330, that can help in comprehending small changes anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, the shifting works but the issue with that is the x value is obtained from datenum() and later i need to convert it back to time format by using datetick('x',13); this will not work after the shift though.....setting xlim between 736330 and 736331 doesnt work, it simply round everything up to 736331

Comment: Well, you should shift it back before the conversion. Either you're trying to plot as "736331", which you can shift, or you're trying to plot as "12/03/2016" in which case you don't need the shifting. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Hi Andras, thanks for that. So basically I have an array of numbers like 143715 and I converted them into cell of times 14:37:15 using datestr(). This is my time cell which i have more than 2000 entries. then I use datenum(time,13) to convert the into numbers so that I can plot them on the x axis. The list of 736330.xxxxx I have is after that datenum() function. I then use datetick() to convert the x axis back into the HH:MM:SS format. The issue is that Octave plot either round up those numbers to 736331 or round them down to 736330, at the end I have 2 vertical bars.

Comment: problem sorted, need to switch to graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot"), then it reads the decimal places

Comment: Ah, I see. Using gnuplot for plotting seems the best solution anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL uses class single to represent numbers. So any graphics_toolkit which uses OpenGL (qt and fltk) have that problem with single precision.

So either switch graphics_toolkit to gnuplot which uses double or remove the constant part in your case x=x-x(1) after creating the ticklabels with datenum so that single precision is enough to distinguish values.